# Как поставить лайк API VK

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, like

Как поставить лайк, используя API от Вконтакте?
часть кода, который у меня написан:

```
    final int item_id = 0;
    final String type = "post";
    final String owner_id = "135088235";
    final double vers = 5.60;
    final String sity = "https://vk.com/idcyperxaker?w=wall135088235_9347";
    final VKApiPost post = new VKApiPost();
    setLike("post", "135088235", post.id);

    public static String setLike(String type, String owner_id, int item_id ) {
    final String[] res = {""};
    VKRequest request = new VKRequest("likes.add", VKParameters.from("type", type, "owner_id", owner_id, "item_id", item_id));
    request.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");
                res[0] = jsonObject.getString("likes");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
    });
    return res[0];
}
```

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/likes.add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String setLike(String type, String owner_id, int item_id ) {
        final String[] res = {""};
        VKRequest request = new VKRequest("likes.add", VKParameters.from("type", type, "owner_id", owner_id, "item_id", item_id));
        request.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");
                    res[0] = jsonObject.getString("likes");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}
        });
        return res[0];
    }
```

Вызывать так:

```
setLike("post", "группа", post.id);
```

1. "post" означает что лайкаем Пост в ленте
   2.Группа обозначается со знаком "-", пример:"-135088235"
2. post берем из VkAPiPost и каждая запись идет по id,  это означает что лайкаем определенную запись в ленте

3 переменные нужны: String type, String owner_id, int item_id

Comment: post.id, создал объект, а как его использовать? т.е. в него надо что-то поместить, а что?

Comment: VKApiPost у вас есть?

Comment: покажите свой код

Comment: final int item_id = 0;
        final String type = "post";
        final String owner_id = "135088235";
        final double vers = 5.60;
        final String sity = "https://vk.com/idcyperxaker?w=wall135088235_9347";
        final VKApiPost post = new VKApiPost();
        setLike("post", "135088235", post.id);

Comment: Обновите свой вопрос с кодом...ничего же не понятно

Comment: обновил  в вопросе

Comment: 1.Группа обозначается со знаком "-", пример:"-135088235"

Comment: а для стены без - , я вкурсе, но мне нужно универсально. про разность группы и стены я вкурсе.

Comment: Вам вообще посты в ленту приходят с группы в RecyclerView?

Comment: нет не с группы. скажем так, присылают ссылки, которые нужно пролайкать и они могут быть и с группы, и со стены пользователя и т.д.

Comment: Очередной накрутчик лайков)

Comment: что то вроде :-)

Comment: ссылка в VKApiPost вставляется таким образом?
        final VKApiPost post = new VKApiPost("https://vk.com/immoralali?w=wall-113026374_76806");